A word that means "the father of his son-in-law"
Is there a word in English that means "father of my/his/her son/daughter-in-law"? There are words with that meaning in other languages.
If not, is there a more succinct way to put it? Less than 6 words...

See this similar question.

@SeowjoohengSingapore perfect.
Should I close the question?

English has few words for family relationships compared to some other languages.

The father of my daughter-in-law is my daughter-in-law's father.
The mother of my son-in-law is my son-in-law's mother.
There are no special words for these relationships.

that's a good start! I saw the formula I mentioned on the BBC and I thought it was a bit wordy

In practice, if you are speaking about your son-in-law's parents, it is likely that the person you are speaking to knows your son-in-law. You would use this shared knowledge, and use personal names.
For example, if you son-in-law is named "David", and you are talking to someone who knows David, then you would say "David's father".  It might be likely that in a real conversation, you'd first have mentioned and named your son-in-law before talking about his father, so this is a common and practical conversational practice:

Do you know our son-in-law, David?
I've met him.
Well next month, we're going on a camping holiday with his parents. David's father is a retired army sergeant!

The conversation builds, providing context, so confusing expressions like "the father of my son-in-law" are not actually likely to be used very often.

'if you son-in-law is named "David", and you are talking to someone who knows David, then you would say "David's father". ' - absolutely this.
